# 2.2K ohm resistor in series with 1A power linear supply circuit, is that right?

Tags: power-supply, linear

[image]

Here's right after the bridge there's 2.2k resistor in series with the regulator.
This circuit is supposed to provide 1A current to the load! is that correct?

Comment: I think you know the answer. :)  Clearly if the average current is 1A, the voltage drop across that resistor would cut off the voltage supplied to the regulator.  Something is wrong.

Comment: AngeloQ is right. Even if it's a 2R2 still it wouldn't make sense because power rating is 1W. By the way, for efficient filtering under that level of loading conditions, inductors can be a better option than resistors.

Comment: The secondary should be marked 2.4kV. Then it will be fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think that can possibly be correct. Maybe a typo for 2.2 ohms, which would be a plausible inrush current limiting resistor (but 1W rating wouldn't be enough).  I would treat the entire design with great suspicion.

Comment: That's exactly what i thouht, And i just looked at the breadboard circuit but i didn't see any series resistors.

Answer (score 7):

The breadboard picture used at [the site responsible for this schematic](http://www.electronicshub.org/0-28v-6-8a-power-supply-circuit-using-lm317-2n3055/) seems to suggest that they really did use a 2.2kΩ resistor. I've circled it in red -- it has clearly visible red-red-red color bands.

[image]

Having this resistor in the location shown in the schematic might make the circuit *appear* to work with no load connected (e.g, just a multimeter, as seen in their demo video), but would make it collapse under any real load. You'd probably have trouble getting it to even light an LED.

What's not quite clear, though, is whether they actually connected the resistor in the way shown in the schematic. It's hard to tell exactly what's going on in the photo, but it almost looks as though the resistor might be connected between the power and ground rails of the breadboard, or possibly even between the power rail and itself (!).

Either way -- don't use this design. It's a poorly conceived and dangerous substitute for a bench power supply.

Comment: yeah, both resistor pins are connected to the top line of the breadboard, awkward!

Answer (score -3):

It's either a typo or someones homework!  Are we doing your home work?

The purpose of the resistor is two fold:

1. It helps cut down a little on the ripple from the full wave.
2. It's a sacrificial lamb in case something become shorted.